# How can I use Valet to serve 2 directories on a subdomain like api.domain.test and spa.domain.test?

Tags: laravel, laravel-valet

I have tried `valet link api.domain` but it shows 502 Bad Gateway. My folder structure is basically very simple. I am using valet park on `~/Sites` and there is a `backend` and `frontend` folder in that `~/Sites` directory. I basically want to access `api.domain.test` and `spa.domain.test` instead of `backend.test` and `frontend.test`.

The reason is using Laravel Sanctum with XSRF cookie protection. The domain + TLD must be same for the cookies to work. I have also tried `valet proxy` but that only worked properly for `frontend.test` being mapped to `localhost:3000` where I serve my Next.js. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the following

```bash
cd ~/Sites/backend

valet link api.domain
```

```bash
cd ~/Sites/frontend

valet link spa.domain

valet proxy spa.domain http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

Comment: Doing so does not resolve the issue as now both ```api.domain.test``` and ```spa.domain.test``` both are pointing to the ```frontend.test```

Comment: @MuhammadYasir How do you conclude that both `api.domain.test` and `spa.domain.test` both point to `frontend.test`? `api.domain.test` & `backend.test` will serve from `~/Sites/backend` while `spa.domain.test` & `frontend.test` will serve from `~/Sites/frontend`

Comment: Upon adding the proxy for ```spa.domain.test``` to point to the ```http://127.0.0.1:3000```  the Valet is transferring traffic from all wild card subdomains of ```domain.test``` like  ```api.domain.test```,  ```spa.domain.test``` and  ```foo.domain.test``` to ```frontend.test```

Comment: @MuhammadYasir Proxy for **spa.domain.test** to point to `http://127.0.0.1:3000` would be proxying traffic to a particular port `3000` in this case while normally the http traffic is via port **80** and **443** is what I understand. So proxying to a particular port should not transfer all wild card traffic is what I guess. I'm not very conversant with the proxying stuff so please let me know if my understanding is correct or otherwise.

Comment: I encountered the same issue that both URLs point to the frontend.

You'll need to check if the proxies and links are point correctly.

`valet proxies` 
`valet links`

The order might be important also. Proxy first before Link.

Comment: @JericoPulvera You can see in my question that proxy and links are pointing to right directories https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73286361/using-valet-to-serve-two-projects-on-sub-domains-using-proxy

Comment: You should only have 1 link and 1 proxy.

You should unlink the app valet unlink app.nuxtodo