# Using Valet to serve two projects on sub domains using proxy

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js, laravel-valet

I have two projects one is API(`Laravel APP`) and another one is a frontend app(`Nuxt APP`). I want to serve these projects on the same domain using `valet` on my local. Problem is that I'm not able to do so as both my subdomains are pointing to the frontend app(`Nuxt APP`). Following are the steps to reproduce the issue

**Step 1:**

Here each subdomain has been registered using the following commands and is pointing to the right directory,

`valet link api.nuxttodo`

`valet link app.nuxttodo`

Note: At this point, if I access `api.nuxttodo.test` it do successfully open the API(`Laravel App`)

Two `links`(sub-domains) that are generated after running these commands are as follows
[image]

**Step 2:**

After that I have added a proxy for the `app.nuxttodo.test` domain using the command because my frontend app(`Nuxt App`) is running on `http://localhost:60539`

`valet proxy app.nuxttodo http://localhost:60539`

One `proxy` is as follows

[image]

**Problem:**

Now issue is that both subdomains are now pointing to the same project. Both `api.nuxttodo.test` and `app.nuxttodo.test` URL are now opening the frontend app(`Nuxt APP`) and I'm not able to access my API(`Laravel App`) which was accessible before running the proxy.

Comment: I'm using Windows system

Answer (score 0):

I'm running the same setup and I only used `valet link` in the Laravel directory.

For the Frontend project, I use `valet proxy`.

You should unlink the frontend `valet unlink app.nuxttodo` as that might be causing the issue.